# How to convert String value to Integer value and want to provide by 'SendKeys' in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have one read method from excel file and return me String value.

ReqQty = 2 in my excel value but it is in string and from UI side application is  not allowing to enter string value in "ReqQty" it is allowing  only Integer value . so here i am not able to provide value in 'ReqQty' field by 'SendKeys' method .

The code is:

```
String Str = ExcelUtils.getcell(1,2) ; 
Integer x = Integer.Valueof(x); 
driver.findelement(By.xpath("xpath").sendkeys(Integer.valueo‌​f(x)); –
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have to fetch that value from excel. Is that a string you want to parse? Have you tried doing some research on parsing?

Comment: String Str = ExcelUtils.getcell(1,2) ->> Which fetched value from excel then   Integer x = Integer.Valueof(x); ->> which convert to integer                                  driver.findelement(By.xpath("xpath").sendkeys(Integer.valueof(x)); here sendkeys only take charsequence so i again make it int .. this i did and tried fetched

Comment: Please update the question --> never put more information into comments!

Comment: String Str = ExcelUtils.getcell(1,2)   ;                                                   Integer x = Integer.Valueof(x);                              driver.findelement(By.xpath("xpath").sendkeys(Integer.valueof(x));

Comment: Which part of:  
*Please update the question --> never put more information into comments* is it that you do not understand? Btw, you got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you going:

```
@Test
public void testParsing() {
    String input = "ReqQty = 2";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ReqQty.*=.*([\\d]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("failed to parse digits from: " + input);
    }

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
}
```

The key elements:

- a regular expression [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) used to "match" for a number of digits within a string
- Integer.parseInt() to turn that substring of digits into a number

Beyond that: it looks like you are overburdening yourself. The error message you got is quite clear "ReqQty = 2" is **not** a string that only contains a number. Thus you have to **extract** that number part from this string. This is really **basic** stuff. If that is already beyond your skills, then fetching data from excel to pass that into selenium is probably beyond your current skills!

Thus: the real answer is - step back and study the java **basics**!

Comment: Yeah i am working on it to improving the Java basics  . thank you  :)

Comment: @Krunal Well, you got a solution now that should be working. So, just for the record; please dont forget about upvoting some and accepting the most helpful answer at some point ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert a string into an integer using [Integer.parseInt(String x)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

```
String x = "17";
int xAsInt = Integer.parseInt(x);
System.out.println(xAsInt);
```

Comment: But , From this i can convert into Int but how can i enter through 'SendKeys()' in webdriver . due to it only takes charsequence .

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string value into an integer you can try this

```
'int x = Integer.parseInt("1234");'
```

or if you are using StringBuilder or StringBuffer you  can try this

```
'Integer.parseInt(myBuilderOrBuffer.toString());'
```

Comment: But , From this i can convert into Int but how can i enter through 'SendKeys()' in webdriver . due to it only takes charsequence

Comment: try this if it's helpful
    'element.sendKeys(String.valueOf(x))'